# How to transpose a query result in SQL Server (rows to columns)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

my query gives me a result as follows:

[image: initial query]

so, i want to transform that result into this:

[image: query transformed]

Note the crossing fields with NULL values.

Comment: You need to use `PIVOT` for this. Google it - it is very easy to learn

Comment: Would be useful to know what your query was that returned the result else it is hard for anyone to give you an answer. Consider adding your SQL to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PIVOT is the way to accomplish this and it can be confusing (at least it was to me) at first.

https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/500811/Simple-Way-To-Use-Pivot-In-SQL-Query

Comment: Thanks. But, what if the number of fields to transpose are dynamic ?

Comment: Thanks to your link i have found another link with a nicer explanation.

http://sqlhints.com/2014/03/18/dynamic-pivot-in-sql-server/

Answer (score 1):

I have found a nice solution to my problem thanks to @[P Doe], for guiding me to the solution.

The link is:

[Dynamic PIVOT in Sql Server](http://sqlhints.com/2014/03/18/dynamic-pivot-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

```
 select id,SN,
 case Part when 'P1' then '1' else null end 'P1',
 case Part when 'P2' then '1' else null end 'P2',
 case Part when 'P3' then '1' else null end 'P3',
 case Part when 'P4' then '1' else null end 'P4',
 case Part when 'P5' then '1' else null end 'P5'
  from table1
```

Comment: Thanks Javlon, but my problem is that I have a dynamic number of fields to transpose .