# How to fetch multiple records from same colum in Excel using Sql Query

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I have a Excel sheet like as follows

```
         ID           |    Service    |   System   |        Timestamp       |
----------------------+---------------+------------+------------------------|        
8148763783013217075-  | Entry         | ZentPeople | 2019-10-14 18:44:38,143|
8148763783013217075-  | ZentRequest   | ZentPeople | 2019-10-14 18:44:38,726|
8148763783013217075-  | BlogRequest   | ZentPeople | 2019-10-14 18:44:38,726|
8148763783013217075-  | Blogresponse  | ZentPeople | 2019-10-14 18:44:39,017|
8148763783013217075-  | ZentResponse  | ZentPeople | 2019-10-14 18:44:39,019|
8148763783013217075-  | End           | ZentPeople | 2019-10-14 18:44:39,020|
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

In the Sheet, the ID and System are same but service and time stamps are Diffrent.
I need a single SQL Query Which could return a single ID and  System but all the service and time stamps in a single row as follows

```
8148763783013217075-  | ZentPeople    | Entry | 2019-10-14 18:44:38,143| ZentRequest |  2019-10-14 18:44:38,726 | BlogRequest| 2019-10-14 18:44:38,726 |Blogresponse | 2019-10-14 18:44:39,017 | ZentResponse | 2019-10-14 18:44:39,019 | End |2019-10-14 18:44:39,020
```

I tried and achieved the above with only VBA and also with 2 SQL query. But it is increasing the computation time. Since i need to process millions of records, Single query can reduce the time to half I guess. So i need a single query to perform it.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Try to bring a minimum set of information: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try and your research. SO is not a free coding service.

Comment: i have edited the post to what i have tried

Answer (score 0):

no SQL just VBA

```
Sub CopyC()
Dim j As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim c As Long
    j = 1
    For i = 1 To Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        c = 3
        Do While Sheet1.Cells(i, 1) = Sheet1.Cells(i + 1, 1)
            If c = 3 Then
                Sheet2.Cells(j, 1) = Sheet1.Cells(i, 1)
                Sheet2.Cells(j, 2) = Sheet1.Cells(i, 3)
            End If
            Sheet2.Cells(j, c) = Sheet1.Cells(i, 2)
            Sheet2.Cells(j, c + 1) = Sheet1.Cells(i, 4)
            c = c + 2
            i = i + 1
        Loop
        Sheet2.Cells(j, c) = Sheet1.Cells(i, 2)
        Sheet2.Cells(j, c + 1) = Sheet1.Cells(i, 4)
        j = j + 1
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Using VBA increases the computation time. so i need it to be done in SQL since i can Paste the record set in a single stretch. The above can be achieved with 2 sql queries but i need itto be done with a single query to increase the performance since i need to process millions of records

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42287383/how-to-transpose-a-query-result-in-sql-server-rows-to-columns - looks like exactly what you want. just convert code to excel

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Let me try